# In Android, How to decode UTF-8 encoded String?

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8, decoding

I 'm using following data to decode the UTF-8 encoded String.

- > Actual string:  秦世俊：用“心”工作 找到属于自己的成就感【开讲啦  20160430】T
- > UTF-8 encoded:  ç§¦ä¸ä¿ï¼ç¨âå¿âå·¥ä½ æ¾å°å±äºèªå·±çæå°±æãå¼è®²å¦  20160430ã"

. Output is same as input. What is the issue?

> Method:

```
public String decodeString(String encodedString) {
            return new String(encodedString.getBytes(), "UTF-8");

    }
```

Comment: I don't think your `encodedString` is utf8 encoded

Comment: It is. You can decode it here: https://mothereff.in/utf-8 , and result would be fine.

Comment: Please post more code so it is reproducable for us. It's pretty unclear what you are doing now. For instance you should start with a string initialized and then `String encodedString = .....;` and so on.

Comment: its simple one line method, please check

Comment: There is nothing to check if you do not provide reproducable code. We cannot even see how and with what you call that function. We do not know what that parameter encodedString contains. So show full code.

Comment: Resolved by:
return new String(encodedString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");

Answer (score 5):

Just Use `String result = URLDecoder.decode(string, "UTF-8");`

Or use this

```
byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
String text = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: No gain, URLEncoder and String encoding has a difference. You can check at these links with same values, result would be different:
https://mothereff.in/utf-8
http://www.freeformatter.com/url-encoder.html#ad-output

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
String s2 = new String(bytes, "UTF-8"); // Charset with which bytes were encoded
```

and if it doesn't work for you

```
String decoded = new String(encoded.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
```

Comment: isn't it the same as mine?